# How to find the first pair of repeated words in a string without hashmap?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find the first pair of repeated words in the string, but I can only get it to find all repeated pairs in order of which word is first in the sentence, not by the first pair. For example in string "I love my anthony so much with all my hearts love" the output should be my, but it gives me love.

```
let Sentence = 'I love my anthony so much with all my hearts love';

function wordRepeat(str) {
  let splitStr = str.split(' ');
  let list = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < splitStr.length; j++) {
      if (splitStr[i].match(splitStr[j])) {
        //repeat = splitStr[i];
        list.push(splitStr[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  //console.log(list);
  return list[0];
}

console.log(wordRepeat(Sentence));
```

The output should be 'my', BUT I get 'love', however 'my' is the correct answer because it is the first pair.

Comment: First you need to define what a _"word"_ is, taking into account contractions and other punctuation. Natural language parsing is fun!

Comment: To be honest, this would be a lot easier if you *did* use a hashmap. You're essentially asking: which pair of repeated words occurs closest to the beginning of the string? If you store the words and their positions (indices) in a hashmap, you could calculate this quickly.

Comment: FWIW, I was confused by this part of your question: "in order of which word in first in the sentence" - because "love" is first in the sentence. Might be worth clarifying!

Comment: @NateBarbettini I made an edit hope that works. I wasn't even sure how to explain it. but thank you. And the reason i didn't want to use a hash map was because I haven't learned them yet. Super newbie here. I wanted to start with easy then move on to optimized.

Comment: @monkey No problem. It's great to ask questions when you are learning!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function getDuplicate(inString){
  const arr=inString.split(/\W+/g);// This is a Regular Expression - See it in use at https://regex101.com/r/X0Cyxx/1
  return arr.find( (word,index) =>
    arr.slice(0,index).includes(word)
  );
}
```

> EDIT:
>   I modified line 2 to include punctuation, as @Phil suggested. Thanks, @Phil!

Comment: Dude, you rock. That worked. This was my first attempt on learning javascript with this example and I was stumped on how to get the first pair. This worked!! Thank you!

Comment: You may want to add some punctuation into your `split()` expression. For example, imagine if it was `I love my, anthony...` (a bad example in this case but highly likely in any sentence)

Comment: No problem, @monkey!

Comment: @AndrewHealey, if its not too much to ask can you explain line 3, where you use find() with parameters word and index and the line 4 after arrow function.

Comment: No problem! I'll add that ASAP.

Comment: Now that you've gone with a non-word character (`\W` aka `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) for your split expression, consider how that handles something like _"Don't you, forget about me. Don't don't don't don't"_